# How can user credetials be leveraged when doing a penetration test for a Windows network?

Tags: windows

Assume the following scenario:

- NTLMv2 only
- Only Vista machines or higher
- Remote desktop disabled throughout network
- No open shares

psexec needs administrative level access. Without any shares or way to remotly login, are any credentials captured useless in such a network?

If not, how could they be leveraged to gain further access?

Comment: if you have the admin's passwords (domain or local) then you have the access you need

Comment: @schroeder Maybe it wasn't clear from my question, but I mean when you have only user level creds, i.e. explicitly non-admin level creds.

Comment: This recall depends on how a specific network is setup.  Is all remote access cut off or can users SSH to other machines?  If they can, is it possible they have elevated privileges on that box?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like user-level passwords in this scenario will be of limited benefit to login to AD-controlled assets. The one thing that might be beneficial is the possibility of re-used passwords for other assets.

You haven't given a lot of detail, but if you can connect to the mail system, you can set up social engineering attacks, or look through user's mail to see if there is other data that you could use.

Otherwise, you need to find admin-level creds. Use what you've got to get you to the brass ring.